# How to show the percentage after the bar chart in react recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I want to show this percentage after the bar chart. I have made this with react recharts

[Check photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGW0b.png)

```js
         <BarChart
            width={window.innerWidth < 900 ? 280 : 380}
            height={200}
            data={data}
            margin={{ top: 20, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5 }}
            layout='vertical'
          >
            {/* <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" /> */}
            <XAxis type='number' tick={false} axisLine={false} />
            <YAxis type='category' dataKey='name' width={window.innerWidth < 900 ? 110 : 120}
              stroke="#fff" style={{ fontSize: '14px' }} />
            <Bar dataKey="pv" stackId="a" fill="#4EDCF0" />
          </BarChart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cutom tooltips to write your own logic to show percentage
Working example if u want to take a look - https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-cache-kx8ze2?file=/src/App.js

```
 <BarChart
  width={500}
  height={300}
  data={data}
  margin={{
    top: 5,
    right: 30,
    left: 20,
    bottom: 5
  }}
>
  <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
  <XAxis dataKey="name" />
  <YAxis />
  <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip />} />
  <Legend />
  <Bar dataKey="amt" barSize={20} fill="#8884d8" />
</BarChart>
```

Custom tooltip

```
const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label }: any) => {


 if (active && payload && payload.length) {
    return (
      <div className="custom-tooltip">
        <p className="label">{`${label} : ${payload[0].value}`}</p>
    <p> percentage :  {percentage (payload)}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }

  return null;
};
```

the function to calculate the percentage

```
const percentage = (data)=>{
  console.log(data[0].value);
      
      const total = 10000 
      const calcualtion = (data[0].value/total) * 100 // total to be replaced by the totla value
      return calcualtion
    

}
```

hope it helps